# Using three brackets to get value from the array in python

Tags: python, arrays, pcap

Extracted `ts` and `buf` from the `pcap` file. And append the values into `scr_ports` array.

And I am not sure about `[i][0][1]` syntax used like below. Could you please explained it please?

```
for ts, buf in pcap: 
    src_ports = []

    src_ports[index].append([ts, buf])

    buf = src_ports[i][0][1]
```

Comment: To get an idea, print `src_ports[i]`, `src_ports[i][0]` and `src_ports[i][0][1]`.

Comment: I don't see any initial value for `i`, but here is what it means... `src_ports[i][0][1]` means take the `i`th value of `src_ports` which is a list. Then take the `0`th element which will be  a list as well. Finally, take the `1`th element and set it to `buf`

Comment: Did you mean `buf = src_ports[index][0][1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[n]` is indexing operator; It gives you n-th item from list. In python you don't have multidimensional arrays, instead of that you have lists of lists. When you have:

```
arr = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
print(arr[0]) # this prints [0, 1], that is 0th list in arr
print(arr[0][0]) # this prints 0, 0th item of 0th item an arr;
# 0th item in arr is [0, 1]; 0th item of that is 0
```

You can expand this to more dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`src_ports` will be a 3D array: `[ [[ts1, buf1], [ts2, buf2], ....], [...], ...]`.

So, the first `[i]` will give you the first 2D array in `src_ports`, the `[0]` will get you the 1st array within it, and `[1]` will give you `buf` inside that 1D array.

Also, it seems strange that you clear the array in the loop. It basically means that you `append` to cleared array each time, which makes no sense to me.